# How to stop messages to show if page refresh when we get a GET parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hi i am trying to implement notifications when certain event happens in PHP. Suppose a user is changing its password and after the form is submitted the action takes it to update.php, if the password was succesfully changed the page will redirect to change.php?err=1 where 1 has a noty notification which shows password changed succesfully. If there was some problem it redirects to change.php?err=2.

The code for updating password in update.php :-

```
$sql="UPDATE user_credentials SET password=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $result->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("si", $hash,$id);

if($stmt->execute()) {
    header('Location: ../change.php?err=1');
}
else {
    header('Location: ../change.php?err=2');    
 }
```

The below code for is for showing messages in change.php.

```
if(isset($_GET['err']))    
{
   $error_id = $_GET['err'];

    if ($error_id == 1) {
    echo "<script> noty({text: 'Password Changed Successfully',layout:   'topRight',timeout: 2500,closeWith: ['click', 'hover'],type: 'success'});</script>";
    }

   else
   if ($error_id == 2) {
   echo "<script> noty({text: 'Something went wrong',layout: 'topRight',timeout: 2500,closeWith: ['click', 'hover'],type: 'success'});</script>";
   }
}
```

Now if the page is refereshed it will show the message again and again. I want to show the message only when it is redirected not on refreshes.

I thought of a workaround using sessions like this:-

```
if ($error_id == 1) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['notify'])) {
      $_SESSION['notify'] = TRUE;
      echo "<script> noty({text: 'Password Changed Successfully',layout: 'topRight',timeout: 2500,closeWith: ['click', 'hover'],type: 'success'});</script>";
    }
}
```

But it stops the message on refreshes but it doesn't show when page is redirected.

I am just starting to learn php so please let me know what I am doing wrong or what else could be better way to solving this problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code for change.php

Comment: @LemuelBotha The code for catching the parameter and showing error is posted. Do you need some other part of code as well.

Comment: Can you show the code for where $_GET['err'] is set, the code of the form and its processing

Comment: Why even use GET?  Put the error message into $_SESSION; for each page, if the session error message var is present, print it and unset it....

Comment: @LemuelBotha I have updated the post with the code

Comment: Have you considered using ajax to update the notification?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey Can you please elaborate with answer on the way you are suggesting it would be a great help

Comment: @LemuelBotha No i haven't considered AJAX. Please elaborate with an answer if AJAX is the best way to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well in addition to 
if(isset($_GET['err'])){}

you can add:

if(isset($_GET['err']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == YOUR_PREV_PAGE){}

In your case it is update.php

Answer (score 0):

This kind of functionality typically works best when you use an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call, that means: without refreshing the page.

You could call `update.php` in the background (see docs of the link pasted above), and decide in the callback of that ajax function what notification to show, based on the response of your `update.php` script.

**EDIT: simple example**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/update-password.php",
  data: {
    user: "some-user",
    pass: "new-pass"
  }
}).done(function(response) {
  // Show notification, decide on contents based on response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SESSION instead of GET for error messages.  Set an error at the time it's detected, prior to your header() call:

```
session_start();

$sql="UPDATE user_credentials SET password=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $result->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("si", $hash,$id);

if($stmt->execute()) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "You password was changed.";
    header('Location: ../change.php');
}
else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "We could not change your password.";
    header('Location: ../change.php');    
}
```

In change.php (and in any other page were a message might be set), do something similar to this:

```
session_start();

if (strlen($_SESSION['error'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['error'];
    $_SESSION['error'] = false;
}
```

Comment: AJAX would/could work; as a matter of fact it's much more "2016" than this sort of solution, but it's more complex to implement, and if you've not done it before and don't have much time, this would be a better solution to start with.